# Symbolic matrix and numpy usage error "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types.."

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, sympy

I was trying to perform a scipy.opimization using minimize function. I am looking to find all the variables like `Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Yc,Yg` such that the error between vector K_P_X and f is minimum. That is `objective function K_P_X-f`should be minimum. I think my mistake is related to the calculation involving `numpy.linalg.norm(sol-f)`where the sol is assigned with a symbolic vector (K_P_X). Due to the data type conflict i am getting this error. If that's the case, Q1. Can anyone please suggest a better way to represent the equality constraint equation (ie. constr1()) such that this error can be avoided. The full code is given below,

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from sympy import symbols,zeros,Matrix,Transpose
import numpy


#Symobolic K matrix
Zc,Yc,Zg,Yg=symbols("Zc Yc Zg Yg",real=True)
A,Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,E,G,L=symbols("A Iz Iy J kz ky E G L",real=True,positive=True)
E=10400000;G=3909800;L=5

def phi_z():
    phi_z=(12*E*Iy)/(kz*A*G*L**2)
    return phi_z
def phi_y():
    phi_y=(12*E*Iz)/(ky*A*G*L**2)
    return phi_y

K_P=zeros(12,12)
K1=Matrix(([E*A/L,0,0],[0,(12*E*Iz)/((1+phi_y())*L**3),0],[0,0,(12*E*Iy)/((1+phi_z())*L**3)]))
K2=Matrix(([G*J/L,0,0],[0,E*Iy/L,0],[0,0,E*Iz/L]))
Q1=Matrix(([0,Zg,-Yg],[-Zc,0,L/2],[Yc,-L/2,0]))
Q1_T=Transpose(Q1)
Q2=Matrix(([0,Zg,-Yg],[-Zc,0,-L/2],[Yc,L/2,0]))
Q2_T=Transpose(Q2)
K11=K1; K12=K1*Q1; K13=-K1; K14=-K1*Q2; K22=Q1_T*K1*Q1+K2; K23=-Q1_T*K1; K24=-Q1_T*K1*Q2-K2; K33=K1; K34=K1*Q2; K44=Q2_T*K1*Q2+K2

K_P[0:3,0:3]=K11; K_P[0:3,3:6]=K12; K_P[0:3,6:9]=K13; K_P[0:3,9:12]=K14; K_P[3:6,3:6]=K22; K_P[3:6,6:9]=K23; K_P[3:6,9:12]=K24 ;K_P[6:9,6:9]=K33; K_P[6:9,9:12]=K34; K_P[9:12,9:12]=K44

##Converting Upper triangular stiffness matrix to Symmetric stiffness matrix##           
for i in range(0,12):           
    for j in range(0,12):
        K_P[j,i]=K_P[i,j]

K_P = K_P.subs({A: 7.55})
K_P = K_P.subs({Zc: 0})
K_P = K_P.subs({Zg: 0})

X= numpy.matrix([[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]])
K_P_X=K_P*X
f= numpy.matrix([[-9346.76033789],[1595512.77906],[-1596283.83112],[274222.872543],[4234010.18889],[4255484.3549],[9346.76033789],[-1595512.77906],[1596283.83112],[-275173.513088],[3747408.91068],[3722085.0499]])
function=K_P_X-f

def Obj_func(variables):
    Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Yc,Yg=variables
    function=K_P_X-f #K_P_X matrix contains the variables like Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Yc,Yg.
    return function

def constr1(variables):
    sol = K_P_X     #Here the variables are in the symbolic vector K_P_X
    if numpy.allclose(sol, f):
        return 0.00 #If Error is equal to zero hence required accuracy is reached. So stop optimization
    else:
        return numpy.linalg.norm(sol-f)

initial_guess=[10,10,10,0.1,0.1,0.001,0.001]
cons = ({'type':'eq', 'fun': constr1},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: -variables[3]+1},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: variables[3]-0.001},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: -variables[4]+1},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: variables[4]-0.001},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: -variables[5]+0.5},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: variables[5]-0},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: -variables[6]+0.5},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda variables: variables[6]-0})
bnds = ((1, 60), (1, 60),(1, 60),(0.1, 1),(0.1, 1),(0.001, 0.5),(0.001, 0.5))
res=optimize.minimize(Obj_func,initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

Comment: Have you experimented with small `minimize` problems without any use of `sympy`?  As a general rule you cannot directly use `sympy` variables or functions in `numpy` or `scipy` code.  You have to use a `sympy` `lambdify` function to convert `sympy` code into `numpy` equivalents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i have performed on a smaller function but now, I have a symbolic matrix (K_P) and two vectors (X and f) such that K_P*X=f . I would like to find all the variables in matrix K_P so as to minimize the error function (K_P*X-f). Here X and f are completely known vector. I will add these matrix K_P and vector X to the above question shortly. I will also look creating the equality constraint equation using lambdify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll list some of the things that are wrong here.

- As `hpaulj` said, you can't directly pass SymPy objects to SciPy or NumPy. But you can `lambdify` and then use that in the minimization routine
- Your minimization setup does not make sense. Minimizing a function with the constraint that that same function must be zero... this is not what constrained minimization means. Constraints are something different from the objective.
- It's better to use [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) here which is dedicated to minimizing the norm of the difference (some vector function - target vector).

With that in mind, here is your script reworked:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, lambdify
import numpy

Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Yc,Yg = symbols("Iz Iy J kz ky Yc Yg",real=True,positive=True)
K_P_X = Matrix([[37.7776503296448*Yg + 8.23411191827681],[-340.454138522391*Iz/(21.1513673253807*Iz/ky + 125)],[-9.4135635827062*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) - 368.454956983948*Iy/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125)],[-9.4135635827062*Iy*Yc**2/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) - 368.454956983948*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) - 0.0589826136148473*J],[23.5339089567655*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) + 2.62756822555969*Iy + 921.137392459871*Iy/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125)],[-5.00660515891599*Iz - 851.135346305977*Iz/(21.1513673253807*Iz/ky + 125) - 37.7776503296448*Yg**2 - 8.23411191827681*Yg],[-37.7776503296448*Yg - 8.23411191827681],[340.454138522391*Iz/(21.1513673253807*Iz/ky + 125)],[9.4135635827062*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) + 368.454956983948*Iy/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125)],[9.4135635827062*Iy*Yc**2/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) + 368.454956983948*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) + 0.0589826136148473*J],[23.5339089567655*Iy*Yc/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125) - 2.62756822555969*Iy + 921.137392459871*Iy/(21.1513673253807*Iy/kz + 125)],[5.00660515891599*Iz - 851.135346305977*Iz/(21.1513673253807*Iz/ky + 125) + 37.7776503296448*Yg**2 + 8.23411191827681*Yg]])
f = Matrix([[-1],[-1],[-1],[-1.00059553353],[3.99999996539],[-5.99940443072],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]])
obj = lambdify([Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Yc,Yg], tuple(K_P_X - f))
initial_guess=[10,10,10,0.1,0.1,0.001,0.001]
bnds = ((1, 60), (1, 60),(1, 60),(0.1, 1),(0.1, 1),(0.001, 0.5),(0.001, 0.5))
lower = [a for (a, b) in bnds]
upper = [b for (a, b) in bnds]
res = optimize.least_squares(lambda x: obj(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6]), initial_guess, bounds=(lower, upper))
print(res)
```

Changes:

- Prior to `lambdify`, we should have a SymPy expression. So both `K_P_X` and `f` are SymPy matrices now.
- Lambdified function takes 7 scalar arguments and returns a tuple of components of `K_P_X - f`
- The bounds are separated into lower and upper, as the syntax of `least_squares` requires
- We can't directly pass `obj` to `least_squares`, because it will receive one array parameter instead of 7 scalars. Hence the additional `lambda` step for unpacking the vector.

Believe it or not, minimization works. It returns `res.x`, the minimum point, as

```
  [  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.69406332e+01,
     1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-03,
     1.00000000e-03]
```

which looks suspiciously round at first, but this is only because the point hits against the bounds you placed (10, 1, 0.1 and so on). Only the third variable ended up with an inactive constaint.

Comment: Hello Ivan, Thank you for you answer. I have compared the parameters you have got using the least square approximation. I compared these parameters with the required one and found that these are very rough approximation. Will it be better to use optimize.minimize function in scipy for this approach? I have updated the question with the actual K_P matrix and vectors (X and f). I was finding it difficult to put the equality constraint so that at the final optimized parameter values the error function should be minimum (K_P*X-f) or zero.

Comment: Since K_P is symbolic matrix and have all the variables. I don't know how to put this equality constraint for the minimize optimization. Could you help me to put up this equality constraint K_P * X - f = 0 ?

Comment: I wrote above: this is not how minimization works. You don't get to say "minimize so that the minimum is zero". The attempt to put "objective==0" as a constraint is never going to work.

Comment: I have seen in many case minimizing a function will end up in large negative values. In order to restrict the error function to 0, i gave the equality constraint. So you mean that in case of least square optimization, there is no need to give the equality constraint to restrict the error function (K_P * X - f = 0). Can we mention any error tolerance within which the optimization should stop? let say 0<=norm<=1e-4. Also the output contains several vectors, i was just wondering what is grad: array() and jac: array(). I think optimality is the final norm of the objective function. Right?